# How to convert the .csv format which is not a csv file in to JSON format in python?

Tags: python, json, csv

I know most of the conversions happen between a .csv file to json. My question here is I **don't** have a .csv file, I just receive a set of output from a source in the .csv format (prints in csv format) and need to convert and **print** in JSON format. There won't be any saving in a file. The printed values directly will be stored in the database.
(I have seen so many solutions, but everything applies for files.)

**Example Input**:

```
heading1,heading2,heading3;rowa1,rowa2,rowa3;rowb1,rowb2,rowb3;
```

I need to convert this in to JSON format in python2.

**Expected Output**:

```
[
  {
   heading1:rowa1,
   heading2:rowa2,
   heading3:rowa3
  },
  {
   heading1:rowb1,
   heading2:rowb2,
   heading3:rowb3
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following, splitting the feilds as needed:

```py
data = "heading1,heading2,heading3;rowa1,rowa2,rowa3;rowb1,rowb2,rowb3;"
lines = data.split(';')
headers = lines[0].split(',')
output = [{h: d for h,d in zip(headers,line.split(','))} for line in lines[1:-1]]
print(output)
```

Comment: May I know why it is not in order like heading1,heading2,heading3?@Keldorn

Comment: If you're using python 2, dictionaries are not ordered (this changed in python 3). If you need the dictionaries to be ordered, use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have been struggling with this like 2 hours.@Keldorn.